# public static final variable in an imported java class

Tags: java, static, final, public, recompile

I happen to come across a Java code at my work place. Here's the scenario: There are 2 classes - `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

`ClassA` has nothing except 4 public static final string values inside it. Its purpose is to use those values like `ClassA.variable` (don't ask me why, it's not my code).

`ClassB` imports `ClassA`. I edited the string values in `ClassA` and compiled it. When I ran `ClassB` I could see it was using the old values - not the new values. I had to recompile `ClassB` to make it use new values from `ClassA`! (I had to recompile other classes that imports `ClassA`!)

Is this just because of JDK 1.6 or I should have known earlier to recompile `ClassB` also! Enlighten me. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the values of the `final` variables from class `ClassA` happen to be compile-time constants, the compiler might have inlined them into the classes using `ClassA` instead of generating a run-time reference. I think, this is what happened in the case you described.

Example:

```
public class Flags {
    public static final int FOO = 1;
    public static final int BAR = 2;
}

public class Consumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(Flags.FOO);
    }
}
```

In this example, the compiler will likely incorporate the value of `FOO` into the code generated for `Consumer` instead of generating the equivalent run-time reference. If the value of `FOO` changes later on, you will have to re-compile `Consumer` in order to have it use the new value.

This is an optimization, which has a few advantages with respect to efficiency and speed of the program compiled. For example, inlining the value might enable further optimizations in the expressions, which use it, for example:

```
int x = Flags.FOO * 10;
```

In this example, inlining the value (here: 1) enables the compiler to notice, that the multiplication makes no difference, and can be omitted alltogether.

Comment: so, you're saying public static final is compile time constant? didn't know that. thought it was just a constant and can't be modified in runtime! thanks for your help.

Comment: Good anwser.  If you want to see that the variable is being inlined, you can use javap to see how the class was compiled, e.g. "javap -c Flags".

Answer (score 3):

It's a binary compatibility issue. References to constant fields are resolved at compile time. The behaviour you are seeing is correct; if you change the values in class A then you will have to re-compile the client (class B). To avoid such problems consider adding constants using an enum type, introduced in Java release 5.0.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose ClassA looks like this:

```
public class ClassA {
    public static final int FOO = 1;
    public static final int BAR = 2;
}
```

If you recompile it, ClassB will continue using the old values.  I guess it could depend on the compiler, but I think this is the typical behaviour.   If you don't want to recompile ClassB everytime a constant in ClassA changes, you'll have to do something like this:

```
public class ClassA {
    public static final int FOO = CONST(1);
    public static final int BAR = CONST(2);

    public static int CONST(int i) { return i; }
}
```

Becuase now javac is unwilling to inline the constants.   Instead it will call the CONST(int) method when ClassA's static initializer runs.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to compile the classes individually?

Use a build system like maven or ant or just let your IDE do it.

The only safe thing to do is to recompile every java which depends of a java class which has changed until every class which could be effected has been re-compiled.

Comment: One or other of the classes may not be under your control.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using the values in a switch you can do this instead:

```
public class A
{
    public static final int FOO;
    public static final String BAR;

    static
    {
        FOO = 42;
        BAR = "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

then the compiler will no longer hard code the values in the other classes that are using them.