# Java static final values replaced in code when compiling?

Tags: java, static, compilation, final

In java, say I have the following

```
==fileA.java==
class A
{  
    public static final int SIZE = 100;
}
```

Then in another file I use this value

```
==fileB.java==  
import A;
class b
{
      Object[] temp = new Object[A.SIZE];
}
```

When this gets compiled does `SIZE` get replaced with the value 100, so that if I were to replace the FileA.jar but not FileB.jar, would the object array get the new value or would it have been hardcoded to 100 because that's the value when it was originally built?

Comment: you mean `new Object[A.SIZE];` ?

Comment: You should get a compiler error here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, the Java compiler does replace static constant values like `SIZE` in your example with their literal values.

So, if you would later change `SIZE` in class `A` but you don't recompile class `b`, you will still see the old value in class `b`. You can easily test this out:

file A.java

```
public class A {
    public static final int VALUE = 200;
}
```

file B.java

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.VALUE);
    }
}
```

Compile A.java and B.java. Now run: `java B`

Change the value in A.java. Recompile A.java, but not B.java. Run again, and you'll see the old value being printed.

Comment: THis is what i was thinking it would do but there are also several answers below this saying the opposite.. anyone have any documentation to back either direction?

Comment: Is there any method to avoid compiler to do this?

Comment: @jesper: One of the best answers I have seen for this issue.Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 8):

You can keep the constant from being compiled into B, by doing

```
class A
{  
    public static final int SIZE;

    static 
    {
        SIZE = 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks: this helped me in a weird scenario: I'm using ikvm to compile java to .NET and my static final fields were rendered as 'const' in C# (which exhibits the same inlining behavior). I wanted to have ikvm generate 'static readonly' which is constant but is not inlined in dependant assemblies. I applied you solution to my java code, and ikvm gracefully generated public static readonly in SIZE = 100; which is ok in C#!

Comment: Hi @MeBigFatGuy Could you explain whats goes on behind the scene when we define a constant inline like final static final String str = "some big string" compared to static { str = "some big string"; } Why static constants gets compiled into classes that references them? Any help would be nice

Comment: When you define a public static final String, all that happens is whereever you reference that field, the compiler will inject a LDC opcode referencing that class's Constant pool in which the LDC is issued. So if you define a field in one class, but reference that variable in 100 classes, each of those other 100 classes will get a copy of that String in each of those class's Constant Pool, and those other classes will not refer to the original class to get the value of the String. This can cause problems if you modify and compile the original class without compiling the 100 other classes.

Comment: If the string in question is really massive, you will have a bunch of really big class files. What ever class references that field will be big. If you really are dealing with massive strings, you probably should be putting them in property files that are on the classpath, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Another route to proving that the behavior is to looking at the generated bytecode. When the constant is "small" (presumably < 128):

```
public B();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #10; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   bipush  42
   7:   anewarray       #3; //class java/lang/Object
   10:  putfield        #12; //Field temp:[Ljava/lang/Object;
   13:  return

}
```

(I used 42 instead of 100 so it stands out more). In this case, it is clearly substituted in the byte code. But, say the constant is "bigger." Then you get byte code that looks like this:

```
public B();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #10; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   ldc     #12; //int 86753098
   7:   anewarray       #3; //class java/lang/Object
   10:  putfield        #13; //Field temp:[Ljava/lang/Object;
   13:  return
```

When it is bigger, the opcode "ldc" is used, which according to the [JVM documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc8.html) "an unsigned byte that must be a valid index into the runtime constant pool of the current class".

In either case, the constant is embedded into B. I imagine, since that in opcodes you can only access the current classes runtime constant pool, that this the decision to write the constant into the class file is independent of implementation (but I don't know that for a fact).

Comment: You can get that bytecode from a `*.class` file by using the `javap` tool that's included with the JDK.

Answer (score 4):

Woo - you learn something new everyday!

Taken from the Java spec...

> Note: If a primitive type or a string
>   is defined as a constant and the value
>   is known at compile time, the compiler
>   replaces the constant name everywhere
>   in the code with its value. This is
>   called a compile-time constant. If the
>   value of the constant in the outside
>   world changes (for example, if it is
>   legislated that pi actually should be
>   3.975), you will need to recompile any classes that use this constant to get
>   the current value.

Comment: Really? Replacing a jar implies replacing the class, which is compiled.  So that statement does not validate your 'not replaced' claim.  A quick decompile of the class file would reveal the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The important concept here is that the `static final` field is initialised with a *compile-time constant*, as defined in the JLS. Use a non-constant initialiser (or non-`static` or non-`final`) and it wont be copied:

```
public static final int SIZE = null!=null?0: 100;
```

(`null` is not a *compile-time constant`.)

Comment: I think creating a dummy CONST() method and then doing "SIZE = CONST(100);" would be easier to read.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/12065326/290254

Answer (score 2):

Actually I ran into this bizarreness a while ago.

This will compile "100" into class b directly.  If you just recompile class A, this will not update the value in class B.

On top of that, the compiler may not notice to recompile class b (at the time I was compiling single directories and class B was in a separate directory and compiling a's directory did not trigger a compile of B)

Answer (score 1):

As an optimization the compiler will inline that **final** variable.

So at compile time it will look like.

```
class b
{
      Object[] temp = new Object[100];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing should note is: static final value **is known at compile time**
if the value is not known at compile time,  compiler **won't** replaces the constant name everywhere in the code with its value.

```
  public class TestA {
      // public static final int value = 200;
      public static final int value = getValue();
      public static int getValue() {
        return 100;
      }
  }

public class TestB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestA.value);
    }
}
```

first compile TestA and TestB, **run TestB**

then change TestA.getValue() to return 200, compile TestA, **run TestB**, TestB will get the new value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDLYT.png)

Answer (score 0):

## There is an exception to this:-

> If static final field is null at the time of compiling then it doesn't get replaced with null **(which is actually its value)**

A.java

```
class A{
     public static final String constantString = null;
}
```

B.java

```
class B{
     public static void main(String... aa){
         System.out.println(A.constantString);
     }
}
```

> Compile both A.java and B.java and run **java B**
>
> > Output will be **null**

---

> Now Update **A.java** with following code and compile only this class.

```
class A{
     public static final String constantString = "Omg! picking updated value without re-compilation";
}
```

> Now run **java B**
>
> > Output will be **Omg! picking updated value without re-compilation**

Answer (score -2):

Java does optimise these sorts of values but only if they are in the same class. In this case the JVM looks in A.SIZE rather than optimizing it because of the usage case you are considering.

Comment: what kind of usecase would cause it to replace vs not replace the value at compile time?

Comment: that is wrong, if it is a compile-time constant, it will be substituted at compile time, no matter in which class it is defined or used.