# Assigning private static final field member using spring injection

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to achieve such an assignment. The [article](http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=105) here deals with `private static` field members but it does not help in this case as final members cannot be assigned.

Justification for using `private static final` as a qualifier for the member:

- The data member is a ServiceClient so it makes sense to have it attached to type as it does not depend on the instance. Its thread safe too, so it will improve performance as I will not initialize the client for each instance.
- The service client itself is a bean, having singleton scope. Hence actually there is only one instance. Since there will always be one instance, there is no point in allowing reassignment.
- Since this client is only be used by methods of this class, it is private.

I am not exactly sure if this is an anti-pattern, but if it is then do my justification qualify to use it? If yes, then how can it be done. If no, then please suggest an alternative (and I would still be interested to know how can this be achieved, just for knowledge purposes).

Comment: If you don't initialize a `final` member on the spot or in a constructor, you can't mark it as final - that's Java programming language design, sorry. A similar case are CDI injections, where the injected fields are often package private (and not final either) to make injection for unit tests possible w/o using setters.

Comment: You can use reflection on the class along with reflection on the `Field` class itself for that field to remove its `final` modifier. Check out [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) for the nitty gritty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do, is not at all possible.

The most fundamental reason is that Java replaces `static final` "variable" occurrences in the code with the actual values (since it's of course known at compile time). Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5173424/2504224) SO answer for more details.

Even if you don't use `final`, Spring still won't allow you to inject a value into the `static` variable directly. You would have to use a setter like:

```
@Value("${my.name}")
public void setPrivateName(String privateName) {
    Sample.name = privateName;
}
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7253751/2504224) SO answer for more.

Comment: alternatives(given the constraints I have used as justification)?

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on that later on