# Static final variable has the old value after rebuilding

Tags: java, android

This is my `Config` class:

```
public class Config
{
  public static final String urlApi = "http://127.0.0.1/api/";
}
```

Whenever I want to change the location, I have to change the value of this variable:

```
public class Config
{
  public static final String urlApi = "http://192.168.50.101/api/";
}
```

In this case, the value is:

> "http://192.168.50.101/api/"

But in debugging mode I saw that "urlApi" has the old value, old IP address. Its weird. How do I fix it ?

Comment: The value will never change if you set it as final.

Comment: So if i say: urlApi = "something new" and buid project, urlApi will never be "something new" ?

Comment: Absolutely not. If a variable is declared as final it means that it's initialized only one time

Comment: if the line above is somewhere else in your code, you cannot change it's value after you initially set it. It is `final`

Comment: If you write `urlApi = "something new"`, you will get a compiler error.  That's what `final` means.

Comment: Think of final as meaning it is a constant. Once you set it, it's done. You cannot change what that variable references.

Comment: What part of the word final do you not understand?

Comment: I'm a beginner, and first time work with final variable, i don't get it. I stop the program, change hard-coded string, and build again, the value is not changed.

Comment: Final refers to runtime ?, we can't change that variable in runtime, that is my understanding.

Comment: Compile time constants. They are fun: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173372/java-static-final-values-replaced-in-code-when-compiling  - not making them final actually helps but there are other ways around. Like passing them through a method that does nothing to them before assigning them to their `final` destination.

Comment: Maybe you didn't save the ```.java``` file before rebuilding.

Comment: Why did I receive so many minuses, I think some didn't understand my question. :)

Comment: @TariqN, I guess you got the downvotes because your question is not clear. Apart from the last word in the questions title you do not mention that the problem occurs after _building_ your code with the new configuration. Most probably assume you want to change it at runtime (which obviously fails because of the `final`).

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. I go to "Clean project" and then again "Make Project", i think this is explanation.

> Note: If a primitive type or a string is defined as a constant and the value is known at compile time, the compiler replaces the constant name everywhere in the code with its value. This is called a compile-time constant. If the value of the constant in the outside world changes (for example, if it is legislated that pi actually should be 3.975), you will need to recompile any classes that use this constant to get the current value.

Comment: The assumption about the compile time constant in your answer is probably correct. A decent IDE should detect this situation though and trigger a rebuild of the affected classes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_nonaccess_modifiers.htm

There are the different **Access Modifiers**

Answer (score 0):

You must change:

```
public class Config {
    public static final String urlApi = "http://192.168.50.101/api/";
}
```

to:

```
public class Config {
    public static String urlApi = "http://192.168.50.101/api/";
}
```

The `final` keyword means that the String is a constant - not a variable. This is, it can't be changed. Removing `final` will allow the String to be changed whenever you want as normal.

Comment: Is Config a nested class? If it is, are you calling urlApi with Config.urlApi?

Comment: No, Config is not a nested class.

Comment: Well, if you are using urlApi = "newURL"; and the value of urlApi isn't changing and it's not final, then you must be setting the same, old value to urlApi.

Comment: I don't want to change value in runtime. Read again the question :)